# Rails 4, how to add model callback to end of chain from concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, callback, before-save

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  include UploadLoginc

  before_save do
    p "before model"
  end
end

module UploadLoginc
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_save do
      p "before module"
    end
  end
end
```

How can I add a `before_save` callback in UploadLoginc to the end of `before_save` callback chains?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot, but you could have another concern for the later callback and include the concern after your model callback so that they are registered in a proper order.

```
module UploadLoginc_before
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_save :do_something_first
  end
end

module UploadLoginc_after
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_save :finally_do_this
  end
end

class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  include UploadLoginc_before

  before_save :inbetween_do_this

  include UploadLoginc_after
end
```